# Java DataStructure for writing 4 pieces of information

Tags: java

I need to extract two pieces of information about two IP addresses and then write those information plus two addresses.
I was thinking of a Set of Pairs for IP addresses, but by which data structure I can write all these information?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain better with some sample data ?

Comment: yes sure.
I have a pcap file containing some network captured traffic. I need to explore number of flows (a conversation between a source and destination IP Address). Then find the characteristics of this traffic, such as finding length and time-arrival.
all these together i need to write these information like
192.168.1.65, 217.174.16.1, 245684(byte), 1.0523(sec)

those IP addresses' type are Byte.

Comment: maybe your looking for tuples.http://javatuple.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
PcapPacketHandler<String> jPacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>(){
            int totalLength = 0;
            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {
                        Ip4 ip = new Ip4();
                        String sIP;
                        String dIP;
                        if (packet.hasHeader(ip) == false){
                            return;
                        }
                         totalLength = totalLength+ ip.getPayloadLength();
                         sIP = org.jnetpcap.packet.format.FormatUtils.ip(ip.source());
                         dIP = org.jnetpcap.packet.format.FormatUtils.ip(ip.destination());
                         System.out.println("SIP = "+sIP+"  "+"destIP = "+dIP+" "+"Payload Length = "+ip.getPayloadLength());
                         System.out.println("Total Length = "+totalLength);
                }
      };

        pcap.loop(10, jPacketHandler, "");
        pcap.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this isn't a Javascript app, you could use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) as it provides a concise way to read/store multiple pieces of data together. Check out the [JSON Java Documentation](http://www.json.org/java/) for details about classes, and to download the related source.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just writing the information you could always use a Hashmap.  Unless you know what you're planning to do with the data, it's hard to say what's best.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a custom class (POJO), and depending on how you want to write it make it `Serializable`. That way you can clearly name your fields (and getters and setters) making your code easier to read (and extend).

Comment: All i need is then plot a graph based on those two statics I extracted. Can you give me clue about your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this...

```
class BigClass { //<br>
   private IPAdreess  addr1; //<br>
   private IPAddress  addr2;  //<br>
   private SomeInfo   additionalInfo;//<br>

   //implement accessors//<br>

   //implement equals, hashCode//<br> 

}//<br>
```

IPAddress, SomeInfo are  your user types. In java, InetAddress represents IP address. This may be much more than your custom type.

The selection of suitable data structure of "set" could be decided many factors.. Do you want to retain the order?  Do you populate it via multiple threads? How many entries you expect in the set? 100s?  A million?

Why not post your code?  It may be easier to give feedback with real code..

Comment: im using jnetpcap library, wonder if u r familiar with it. 
here is the part im reading n displaying the ip addresses and also the length, i need to extract one more piece of information which is time-arrival too.

Comment: PcapPacketHandler<String> jPacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>(){ int totalLength = 0;
  public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {
   Ip4 ip = new Ip4();String sIP;String dIP;
   if (packet.hasHeader(ip) == false){return;}
totalLength = totalLength+ ip.getPayloadLength();
sIP = org.jnetpcap.packet.format.FormatUtils.ip(ip.source());
dIP = org.jnetpcap.packet.format.FormatUtils.ip(ip.destination());

Comment: i  cant post it in a proper form, how can i do that?

Comment: Use "Code sample" in the small editor bar. You may have to go back to the  question and do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what graph you exactly want to plot. What I would do is

1. Dump all data into an sql database
2. Run a query to produce input for your chart.
3. Plot the chart e.g. with [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) or even Excel

I imagine a query along the line

```
select source_ip, dest_ip, sum(time), sum(sent_bytes) group by source_ip, dest_ip
```